# Excel Formula with SUMIF

Tags: excel

I have to colums, E and F:

```
E:
'Invoiced Amount'
£150
£600
£300
£375

and F:
'Paid On'
January 2nd
February 3rd
```

Only invoices that have been paid have a date in column F.  I want to create a formula that basically adds up the totals in column E **if** there is a date in column F.  How can I do this? I have gotten as far as thinking I might need to use =SUMIF, but I am not sure.

It's been a long time since I have done Excel Formulas.  Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
=SUMIF(F2:F10,"<>",E2:E10)
```

it sums all values in range `E2:E10` if corresponding values in range `F2:F10` are not empty

Comment: Wow, that was quick.  Why does the condition have to be in quotes?  Thank you very much, It works perfectly.

Comment: It's a syntax of this formula:) You could use either string with condion, either some value as condion. E.G. if you need to sum all cell in column `E` where corresponding cells in column `F` are equal to `1`, you could use `=SUMIF(F2:F10,1,E2:E10)`, but if you need to sum all cells in col `E` where values in col `F`, say, greater then `1`, you have to use *string condition* : `=SUMIF(F2:F10,">1",E2:E10)`

Comment: Everything that's not a number, name appearing in Name Manager or function needs to be in quotes to "tell" Excel that it's a literal.

Comment: huh. cool! I am just waiting to acccept your answer but thank you for teaching me.